# setString NSMutableString

Tags: xcode, calculator, nsmutablestring, setstring

I am new to programming in XCode, and as a first familiarisation exercise, I would like to make a small Calculator app. So obviously I came upon a few problems:
I try to have the user use buttons to type the digits and operators into a string, which he then sees. When I use

```
displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", displayString, operatorString];
```

everything works fine. Then I decided to work with NSMutableStrings in order to get deletebuttons. I changed the headerfile appropriately, after which I still the earlier NSString functionality (? because NSMutableString inherits from NSString?) And then I got the following problem:

```
[displayString setString:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@", displayString);
```

Even when this is the first method I call, I still get nul. I 
What am I doing wrong?

Unrelated, is there a way to have this string write to a sort of function: I would like to be able to do

```
result = contentof:displayString
```

or something a like. 
Any ideas in how I could do this?

Answer (score 6):

`NSString` doesn't have a `setString:` method. ([Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html))

For this case, you'd need an [`NSMutableString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here's how you'd implement it:

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:"%@%@", displayString, operatorString];
```

... and then to change it:

```
[mutableString setString:@"test"];
```